# Adding Unique values and excluding a constant value

Tags: excel, countif

I need to add unique values and make sure that I am excluding a constant value (eg 10)

```
Acct #        Value
9xxx123        50
9xxx123        50
9xxx123        10
9xxx123        15
9xxx234        10
9xxx234        25
9xxx234        25
9xxx234        30
```

The answer should be: `9xxx123 = 65` and for `9xxx234 = 55`

On a different thread someone already suggested using the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$9=E2)*$B$2:$B$9)/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,E2,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9)+($A$2:$A$9<>E2)))
```

But now I need to exclude the constant value.

Thanks!

Leo

Comment: How is the constant determined? can other values be duplicated?

Comment: The constant is just a given value of 10 that is generated automatically. No I am trying to sum only unique values and to exclude the constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add skip 10 to the existing:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$9=E2)*($B$2:$B$9<>10)*$B$2:$B$9)/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,E2,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9,"<>" & 10)+($A$2:$A$9<>E2)+($B$2:$B$9 = 10)))
```

[image]